Connecting to Google Cloud SQL from Cloud functions gen2
I am having trouble connecting to cloudSQL from CF gen2. I was using gen1 functions and deploying them with gcloud functions deploy command. The connection is through Unix Socket. Cloud SQL runs on public IP. The runtime of the cloud functions is php.
The connection from CF gen1 was straighforward, but since gen2 runs on Cloud Run I would need to connect the cloudSQL manually through Cloud Function -> Cloud Run revision according to docs (bottom part - Gen2). I would like to connect to cloudSQL without the need of setting the connection manually. Is there a way to specify it with gcloud functions deploy command, just like for cloud run (docs)? I would prefer solution without terraform, but I am open to the terraform version as well.
I have tried to create the connection manually.

As mentioned in the docs, the gen2 functions does not support natively this behavior on deploy (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-cloud-functions#configure_a_sample_app).
What you can do on your pipeline is to, after deploying the functions, make a cloud run service update using gcloud with the database instance you want, (this is a behavior you can make once per function deploy, as adding the instance will "stay forever" in next deploys until you remove it explicitly)
gcloud run deploy loweredcasefunctionname \
  --region YOUR_REGION_NAME \
  --add-cloudsql-instances INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME

At least, this have worked for us,
Cheers!
